# i18n Drupal Problem

Tags: drupal, internationalization

i have the following problem:

I installed the spanish package for drupal and the i18n module. I enabled the language switcher. I can create english pages and spanish too.
I want to have two menus, one i want to display when the language was spanish and the other when the language is english. in order to that, i created two blocks, and i set the language settings. When i click in english, drupal display the english menu but when i click in spanish, drupal shows me nothing. why?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if i'm correct,i think the reason for this is that the menu items need a valid path in each language for it to work.

so let's say you've got a page '/en/test' - and a menu item which links to this page called 'test_en
then you need to have a translation of that same page in spanish as well for the other menu block.

so for Spanish you need a menu item 'test_es' which points to '/es/test', so you need to have a translation of the 'test' page in spanish as well.

if you don't want to translate the content, you might want to checkout the module http://drupal.org/project/i18nmenu_node